# Angular reactive form is invalid on page load

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, angular-reactive-forms

I have a form where three of my inputs (two fields and 1 checkbox) are `ng-invalid` when the page first loads. The checkbox is the one I'm most concerned about, [because it appears with a red border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hif0m.png) ("this field is required") right off the bat. `ng-invalid` as a class is setting that red border, while `ng-valid` sets a grey border (which I want).

There's some other fields on the page but they're disabled and neither invalid nor valid.

What is setting the form fields as `ng-invalid`? I'm suspecting that there's something wrong with how my `FormGroup` and controls are set up, but I'm not sure what the culprit is. I noticed that `ng-invalid` *is* being added to the `FormGroup` itself, so to me solving that's the key to resolving this.

---

#### component.ts

```js
  constructor(
    private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder
  ) { }

  myFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      // other FormControls
      password: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(MIN_PW)]),
      confirmPassword: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      myCheckbox: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
    }, { validator: PasswordValidation.MatchPassword }
  );

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // etc
  }
```

#### template:

```html
<form [formGroup]="myFormGroup" #myNgForm="ngForm" class="my-form">

  <div>
      <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="password-field half-width">
        <input matInput [type]="hidePassword ? 'password' : 'text'" formControlName="password">
        <mat-error *ngIf="myFormGroup.controls['password'].invalid">Password is required and must contain at least 8 characters.</mat-error>
        <button mat-icon-button matSuffix (click)="hidePassword = !hidePassword" [attr.aria-label]="'Hide password'" [attr.aria-pressed]="hidePassword">
          <mat-icon>{{hidePassword ? 'visibility_off' : 'visibility'}}</mat-icon>
        </button>
        <mat-label>Password</mat-label>
        <mat-hint>Must be at least 8 characters</mat-hint>
      </mat-form-field>

      <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="ml-16 password-field half-width">
        <input matInput [type]="hidePassword ? 'password' : 'text'" formControlName="confirmPassword">
        <mat-error *ngIf="myFormGroup.controls['confirmPassword'].pristine || myFormGroup.controls['confirmPassword'].errors?.MatchPassword">Passwords do not match</mat-error>
        <button mat-icon-button matSuffix (click)="hidePassword = !hidePassword" [attr.aria-label]="'Hide password'" [attr.aria-pressed]="hidePassword">
          <mat-icon>{{hidePassword ? 'visibility_off' : 'visibility'}}</mat-icon>
        </button>
        <mat-label>Confirm password</mat-label>
      </mat-form-field>

    </div>

    <div>
      <p class="full-width">
        <mat-checkbox formControlName="myCheckbox" required>some text</mat-checkbox>
      </p>
    </div>

</form>
```

---

Here's the `ng-invalid` class on the checkbox.

[image]

Comment: Get rid of the `required` inside the `mat-checkbox` maybe? Since you are already setting up that control to be required anyway by code.

Answer (score 1):

> What is setting the form fields as ng-invalid? I'm suspecting that there's something wrong with how my FormGroup and controls are set up, but I'm not sure what the culprit is. I noticed that ng-invalid is being added to the FormGroup itself, so to me solving that's the key to resolving this.

Since you have defined Validators such as `required`, `minLength`, etc and form controls are initialized with empty string, the validation fails and that's the reason for `ng-invalid` class being added. This doesn't mean that the FormGroup and controls setup is wrong. Though you should have default initial value as `false` instead of `''` for myCheckbox FormControl.

Apart from `ng-invalid` class, Angular automatically adds other classes too, as can be seen in one of the screenshot in the question. You need to make use of them **in combination** with `ng-invalid` class.

- `ng-pristine` implies that user hasn't modified the form control. Once user modifies the form control, the `ng-dirty` class would be added.
- `ng-untouched` implies that user hasn't interacted with the form control. Focus into the field and then simply move out (i.e blur) will add `ng-touched` class since user has now interacted with the field.

When any FormControl is invalid, the FormGroup would be invalid too. The above classes would be applied to FormGroup too. So if any FormControl has `ng-dirty` or `ng-touched` class, the same will apply to FormGroup too.

From [docs](https://angular.io/guide/forms#show-and-hide-validation-error-messages) which talks about importance of pristine state. Though it may be related to showing/hiding error message but applies to styling too:

> Pristine means the user hasn't changed the value since it was displayed in this form. If you ignore the pristine state, you would hide the message only when the value is valid. If you arrive in this component with a new (blank) hero or an invalid hero, you'll see the error message immediately, before you've done anything.
> You might want the message to display only when the user makes an invalid change. Hiding the message while the control is in the pristine state achieves that goal.

Comment: Hey @Siddhant , thanks for the info. If I prefill the password fields (using `new FormControl('something'`), they then appear as `ng-valid` but the checkbox is `ng-invalid`. Unfortunately setting `false` to the `myCheckbox` `FormControl` did not change the state of the checkbox (still invalid).

Comment: @Bodrov Setting `false` won't make the checkbox valid. FormControl associated with checkbox will have values as true or false. Instead of empty string, I suggested to use `false`. If you want to prefill it and satisfy the `required` validator, you would need to set it as `true` like `new FormControl(true)`

Comment: Gotcha. Unfortunately I can't go the prefilled route---the checkbox itself has to be clicked on by the user so it can't start in a checked state.

Comment: Agree, that's why in  answer I have suggested to use `ng-invalid` in combination with other classes to style the invalid checkbox. Simply using `ng-invalid` to style won't help. If you can provide stackblitz, I may be able to help you.